# Issue cloning every repository

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been cloning repositories with node and MongoDB but I always run into issues running npm install when I cd into the folder directory.

It has to be me because I happens every time. What am I missing?

Seems like npm install is the 3rd step after 1: git clone "repository link", 2: cd in clone folder.

Please guide me in the right direction.

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

You can run `npm install` from a directory where `package.json` file is located since this is the one which holds all the info regarding packages. 
So just try to make it sure that the directory from where you are firing `npm install` command, have `package.json` file.
Apart from this, just check if you have `npm` installed. Run `npm -v`